# How to enable a feature gate in Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'm create GKE clusters for end-to-end tests programmatically with

```
gcloud container clusters create mereet-e2e-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA-$CI_PIPELINE_IID --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --no-enable-stackdriver-kubernetes --no-enable-autoupgrade --preemptible --enable-kubernetes-alpha --quiet
```

Afaik feature flags are enabled with `kubeadm init` which is run by GKE. I searched carefully through options of `gcloud`, `gcloud container`, `gcloud container clusters` and `gcloud container clusters create` as well as their `gcloud alpha` and `gcloud beta` equivalents with no clue how to control feature gates.

I would like to activate the feature gate `StartupProbe`.

I tried beta and alpha clusters in the hope that my feature gate is already active in these versions. It's not a problem that the feature will be only available in beta or alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accroding to the docs, StartupProbe is a 1.16 alpha feature, while on GKE you can create clusters up to 1.14.

[image]

So, it won't even be documented in GCP docs. Besides, note that you don't have access to k8s master on GKE. Only to some features.

With `kubeadm` you can do whatever you want.